# I added too much corn starch into my potato cutlets - what do I do now?

Tags: dough, potatoes

I wanted to make a dough so I added cornstarch in my potato cutlets dough and now it tastes like flour.

Comment: Add more potato?

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to throw it away and start over. You could possibly salvage it by adding more potato and other ingredients, however this is not likely to work and you'll end up throwing more food and time away. If you are going to use more ingredients you're better off trying again.